# convert image from [0.0, 1.0] to [0, 255]

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, scikit-image, torchvision

Suppose the image x consists of floats in the range [0, 1],

1. Torchvision adopts the transform of `clip(x*255+0.5, 0, 255).as(uint8)` .
2. Skimage seems similar to torch
3. TensorFlow uses an asymmetric approach

Details on the conversion follow below.

However, while investigating a few things, I found that this method gives an unfairly small chance for values of 0 and 255 compared to other values.

Why do these machine learning libraries use these unfair transformations?

pytorch
https://pytorch.org/vision/main/_modules/torchvision/utils.html#save_image

```py
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
import numpy as np
DICT = defaultdict(list)
def as_uint8(X):
    return np.clip(X * 255 + 0.5, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)

for K, V in Counter(as_uint8(np.linspace(0/256, 256/256, 32 * 256))).items():
    DICT[V].append(K)
print(DICT)
```

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {17: [0, 255], 32: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254], 33: [8, 16, 25, 33, 41, 49, 58, 66, 74, 82, 90, 99, 107, 115, 123, 132, 140, 148, 156, 165, 173, 181, 189, 197, 206, 214, 222, 230, 239, 247]})
```

skimage https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/data_types.html

```py
from skimage.util import img_as_ubyte
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
import numpy as np
DICT = defaultdict(list)

for K, V in Counter(img_as_ubyte(np.linspace(0/256, 256/256, 32 * 256).reshape(-1, 1, 1)).reshape(-1)).items():
    DICT[V].append(K)
print(DICT)
```

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {17: [0, 255], 32: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254], 33: [8, 16, 25, 33, 41, 49, 58, 66, 74, 82, 90, 99, 107, 115, 123, 132, 140, 148, 156, 165, 173, 181, 189, 197, 206, 214, 222, 230, 239, 247]})
```

tensorflow https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/convert_image_dtype

```
import tensorflow as tf
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
import numpy as np
DICT = defaultdict(list)

img = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.linspace(0/256, 256/256, 32 * 256).reshape(-1, 1, 1))
img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, dtype=tf.uint8, saturate=False)
img = tf.reshape(img, -1).numpy()

for K, V in Counter(img).items():
    DICT[V].append(K)
print(DICT)
```

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {33: [0, 17, 34, 51, 68, 85, 102, 119, 136, 153, 170, 187, 204, 221, 238], 32: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254], 17: [255]})
```

my suggestion 1

```py
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
import numpy as np
DICT = defaultdict(list)
def as_uint8(X):
    return np.clip(np.rint(X * 256 - 0.5), 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
for K, V in Counter(as_uint8(np.linspace(0/256, 256/256, 32 * 256))).items():
    DICT[V].append(K)
print(DICT)
```

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {32: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255]})
```

my suggestion 2

```py
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
import numpy as np
DICT = defaultdict(list)
def as_uint8(X):
    return np.clip(X * 256, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
for K, V in Counter(as_uint8(np.linspace(0/256, 256/256, 32 * 256))).items():
    DICT[V].append(K)
print(DICT)
```

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {32: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255]})
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is your question

Comment: you should ask authors of modules why they use these methods.